# twarc2 conversation with some ID values doesn't return output

Tags: twitter, twarc2

## Example 1

For this tweet:

https://twitter.com/UrbanKaoboy/status/1520080172896055296

[image]

using `twarc2 conversation` works fine:

```
twarc2 conversation 1520080172896055296
```

[image]

## Example 2

However, for this tweet:

https://twitter.com/Josh_Young_1/status/1515376888096735239

[image]

`twarc2 conversation` doesn't return anything:

```
twarc2 conversation 1515376888096735239
```

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to get `twarc2` to return output for the second tweet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

twarc uses a search [behind the scenes](https://github.com/DocNow/twarc/blob/36c225228522e7c67de003638c74ecf4878f3a12/twarc/command2.py#L1792). The problem is the default Twitter v2 seach endpoint only returns data for the last 7 days. If you get your account blessed as part of the Academic Product Track you can search the full archive, and can use the `--archive` twarc option to do it.

Comment: For the curious, I'm using twarc2 to convert twitter conversations to Emacs org mode documents: 
https://twitter.com/dharmatrade/status/1520894768511074304